# Blank as last character in a monospace formatted text

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

Writing a documentation, I have some small text examples to give, which should be formatted as monospace text by using backticks. Theses text snippes contains always as last character a blank, which must not be omitted, as it is significant. Unfortunately Asciidoctor omits them.

For example `: ` should be rendered as `:` . But instead it is readered as `:`.

So how does the markup look to get a colon and a blank rendered as preformatted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the built-in attribute `{nbsp}` for non-breaking space in Asciidoctor, which can be used for a blank.

So `` `:{nbsp}` `` is rendered as `:` .